# HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'xx' is not present

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make a simple **Spring MVC** application.

Here's my `HelloController`

```
package com.springapp.mvc;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model,@RequestParam(value = "xx",required
=true)String xx) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Mahdi");

    return "hello";
}
}
```

and the **JSP** file:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>${message}</h1>
<form action="/" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="xx">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to run the application:

```
HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'xx' is not present
```

I'm new to **Spring MVC**, please help.

Comment: Did you enter text into the text field?

Comment: before loading the jsp page I got that error message.

Comment: Why have you mapped the request to `/` for Controller ? And how are you hitting the JSP ?

Comment: You need one controller method to load the page that contains the form and another to handle the form submittal.

Comment: no special reason, by the way without "@RequestParam(value = "xx",required
=true)String xx" everything works fine and I can see the page.

Comment: If required="false" should work too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your use case requires two actions:

1. View and edit the `<form>`
2. Submit the `<form>`

This should be mapped to two handler methods

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getForm() {

    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Mahdi");
    return "hello"; // assume hello.jsp
}

@RequestMapping(params={"submit"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "xx",required=true) String xx) {

    /*
     Do something with submitted parameter
     and return some view name
    */
}
```

When you want to access the form, you make a GET to `/`. When you submit the form, you can also do a GET to `/`, but you would need something else to distinguish the request. Here, I've used `params="submit"`. So you need to change your submit input to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
```

or just put the parameter you're already using (`params={"xx"}`).

Comment: I'm obviously making assumptions here, explain what's happening.

Comment: I got this error: The requested resource is not available. http 404-

Comment: Does that happen when you make a GET request to `/`? Do you have a jsp called `hello.jsp` and is it mapped in your ViewResolver?

Comment: Happy to hear it, the javadoc for the attributes of `@RequestMapping` is very useful. Good luck!

Comment: I just forgot to declare params{"xx"} in @requestmapping!

Comment: I forgot to set my required to false in @RequestParam(value = "xx",required=true), that argument aid in my solution thanks.