# Spring 4 - HTTP Status 400, Required parameter is not present

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, mapping

I have Spring form in **index.jsp**:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>
<body>
<form:form action="save" name="employeeDTO" method="POST">
        <label for="name">Name</label><input id="name" type="text" required><br>
        <label for="surname">Surname</label><input id="surname" type="text" required><br>
        <label for="email">E-mail</label><input id="email" type="email" required><br>
        <label for="salary">Salary</label><input id="salary" type="number" required><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

In **WorkController.java** I try to map form submit (at this moment, it doesn't do anything with data):

```
@Controller
public class WorkController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@RequestParam EmployeeDTO employeeDTO){
        return "saved";
    }
}
```

But I got HTTP 400 Status: `Required EmployeeDTO parameter 'employeeDTO' is not present` with description: `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`

There is **EmployeeDTO.java**:

```
public class EmployeeDTO implements Serializable, DTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private Double salary;

    public EmployeeDTO(){}

    public EmployeeDTO(Long id, String name, String surname, String email, Double salary){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.email = email;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable toEntity() {
        return new Employee(getId(), getName(), getSurname(), getEmail(), getSalary());
    }
}
```

If I remove `@RequestParam EmployeeDTO employeeDTO` from `save` method signature - it works, it redirects to `saved.jsp` file. Earlier, I uses `@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String surname etc` to catch data from HTML forms. Is there any solution to "catch" data from Spring form as DTO object? I wolud be happy if anbyody decides to help me - thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try with `@ModelAttribute` (Visit [ModelAttribute question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423262/what-is-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc) to get clear understanding about it)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute("employeeDTO") EmployeeDTO employeeDTO){
    return "saved";
}
```

I used this `in spring mvc 3.1`

Comment: Thank you, it works :) But will it works with AJAX requests? I saw few month ago like use `@SomeSpringAnnotation EmployeeDTO employeeDTO` and he could map all requests body explicity to DTO.

Comment: @Pneumokok: Yes, it works with ajax request too. I used `$.post()` function to work with ajax.

Answer (score 3):

Use @RequestBody to map all entire body content (Example: JSON) to your DTO object. Use @ModelAttribute for map all the form post parameters to DTO object.

Comment: With @RequestBody I got `HTTP Status 415` with description `The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the previous answers, *@ModelAttirube* is a part of your fix, but, to have the values actually bind to the model attribute, you'll have to add the name attributes on your form, like this

```
<form:form action="save" name="employeeDTO" method="POST">
    <label for="name">Name</label><input id="name" name="name" type="text" required><br>
    <label for="surname">Surname</label><input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" required><br>
    <label for="email">E-mail</label><input id="email" type="email" name="email" required><br>
    <label for="salary">Salary</label><input id="salary" type="number" name="salary" required><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form:form>
```

Comment: Thanks :) I forgot about it, but now with names it works

Answer (score 0):

Use @ModelAttribute to bind your DTO (in Spring form) to a Controller method's parameter.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using spring MVC then make sure you have "@RequestMapping" for "ModelAndView" in your controller for the JSP.
and check your ajax call in jsp page for synatax.
and this url may help you

[HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'xx' is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978333/http-status-400-required-string-parameter-xx-is-not-present)